# Automated file send from remote desktop

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, automation, remote-access

I have a main PC (running WinXP), on which [Remote Desktop Connection Manager](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21101) is installed. I use it to connect to a remote virtual environment (running Win 7). Currently, I am able to copy\paste text and even files between these two systems.

What I am interested in, is to know if there is any way I can send files from the remote system to my local system automatically?

I have few scripts running on this remote system which create logs and other files. I want later process these logs and create automatic email which will include some of this data, but I don't want to copy the files manually from the remote system each time.

**EDIT 1:**

1. The remote system is a company internal server and does not have an internet access.
2. Preferred way to that will be a command line solution so I will be able to set as a repetitive task.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative would be to have an FTP server running on your local machine and to have a scheduled task or tasks copy the necessary files from the remote machine to your machine's FTP server.

This would be harder to set up but would probably be a more appropriate solution.

Comment: I agree. This could be a better solution but I'm not sure whether that's possible to create such direct link between these 2 systems. I have tried to ping the local system from the remote system but I got timed out..

Comment: The local machine (or something inbetween) may be preventing the ping and this doesn't necessarily mean the two computers can't see each other, particularly since you can connect to the remote environment using remote desktop.

Comment: So is there a way to test that I can connect my local system from the remote?

Comment: If you wanted to test whether the FTP server idea would work you would need to set an FTP server up on the local machine and then try to connect to it from the remote machine (either from the command line or using a tool like FileZilla). I'm assuming you know the IP address of your local machine since you say you have tried ping'ing it already.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [robocopy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) for copying of files from one machine to another, assuming they are on the same network.

Use windows scheduler for automatic and regular copying

Answer (score 0):

If possible, you could install something like [DropBox](https://www.dropbox.com/) onto the remote system and have this automatically sync the necessary files to your local system.

It might need some tinkering if you don't want all of the files in a directory.

(Other cloud based file syncing tools are available)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However the remote system is internal server which does not have an internet connection. So using Dropbox or other cloud services like this is impossible.